# Map nested C structures to Lua like SWIG does

Tags: c, struct, lua, swig

Let's say I have C structure like this:

```
typedef struct {
   int id;
   struct {
      int num1;
      int num2;      
   }numbers;
}test_t;
```

Due to the SWIG wrapper I can use it in Lua as:

```
test1.number.num1 = 5
```

It works well but the generated code is too heavy (3000 lines for this example). I will run it an embedded environment. So I want to make it myself in a more simple way.

I know SWIG uses classes and metatables to do this.
Can someone explain and/or show an example how to simply do this?

Comment: Use SWIG or a template library like [Sol2](https://sol2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (needs C++ though).

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here if SWIG has already done this for you.

Comment: The SWIG generated code too heavy for me. I have just a few simple structures.